# Why is there no bronze badge for zero score accepted answers?

Tags: feature-request, badges, accepted-answer, badge-request, zero-score-badges

Why is there no bronze badge for zero score accepted answers? I just got one (my first, excluding a self-answered question).

Comment: It's fairly common. The Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges are more of a consolation prize for toiling away in the backwaters of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Stack Overflow encourages voting. ["Vote early, Vote Often"](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/). The Stack Overflow community wants to see as few zero score accepted answers as possible, so that good content is rated high whereas unhelpful answers are downvoted. There are many badges related to voting. "Tenacious" and "Unsung Hero" are there as a consolation prize, in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

If you are after a new bronze badge, I would go with a badge saying:

> First zero score accepted answer

Feel free to suggest proper name.

Comment: **Neutral Answer** :-)

Comment: **Neutral Acceptance**

Comment: @Nick thanks, but so far all badge names are adjectives describing the person - better stick with this, somehow. :)

Comment: **Promising Unsung Hero** - who wouldn't want that badge?

Comment: @Nick - I've got unsung hero, but I'd vastly prefer to be a sung-about hero.

Comment: @justkt: sure, sung heroes are way cooler ;)

Comment: I got [my](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/226/unsung-hero?userid=447356) Unsung Hero badge when I was really new, less than two months into SO and had no idea what it means for long time, lol.. but was proud to wear that shiny gold badge so early. :-)

Comment: _The hero is yet to be unsung_.